# Install mplayer on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mplayer

Have anyone experienced installing mplayer on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.3)?
I have stuck for a whole day trying everything from install using source code, download the dmg and extract the binary inside. But none works.

**Edited**:
Sorry for not clarifying this question from beginning
Randolph Potter has shown me that OSX Extended MPlayer works.
In fact, what I want is the command line version of mplayer.
I can install it on Mac OS X 10.5.8, but not on 10.6.3

Comment: Can you be more specific? What errors are you getting?

Take a look at `VLC` or `MPlayer OSX Extended` instead, if you're having little luck.

Comment: I cannot launch MPlayer OSX Extended on OSX 10.6.3. As far as I close the `Check for update automatically` dialog, the app will crash.
I have seen guy install it from source code on Mac OS X Leopard, but not on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Is there any output from MPlayer in Console.app after crashing?
btw: MPlayer Extended works fine for me on 10.6.3

Comment: Yes, it works right now. I don't know why it crashed several times before. However, what I really want is command line version (I can install mplayer via `sudo port install mplayer` on 10.5.8, but not on 10.6.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go to macports.org official site and search for mplayer inside available ports. I see there are two packages: `mplayer` cannot be installed on 10.6.x but `mplayer-devel` can. I installed it and be able to do all of the operation. Thanks you guy for sharing.

Comment: these days mplayer seems to install all right

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is installing it with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) - maybe you want to give that a try...

Comment: It failed miserably with this message: 


/var/tmp//ccFaPlU8.s:292:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/var/tmp//ccFaPlU8.s:371:suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/var/tmp//ccFaPlU8.s:421:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/var/tmp//ccFaPlU8.s:504:suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
make[1]: *** [vf_ilpack.o] Error 1
make: *** [libmpcodecs/libmpcodecs.a] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.

Comment: @Phuong: have you upgraded your XCode and migrated your MacPorts? If you still want to use `sudo port install mplayer` you'll need to [migrate your existing install](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use MPlayer from the command line without compiling it yourself sweep through the MPlayer Extended application package. Look what i have found at

`/Applications/MPlayer\ OSX\ Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended-mt.mpBinaries/Contents/MacOS/mplayer`

```
theBook:~ lennart$ /Applications/MPlayer\ OSX\ Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended-mt.mpBinaries/Contents/MacOS/mplayer -v
MPlayer SVN-r30478-4.2.1 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team
CPU vendor name: GenuineIntel  max cpuid level: 13
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz (Family: 6, Model: 23, Stepping: 10)
extended cpuid-level: 8
extended cache-info: 201351232
Detected cache-line size is 64 bytes
CPUflags:  MMX: 1 MMX2: 1 3DNow: 0 3DNowExt: 0 SSE: 1 SSE2: 1 SSSE3: 1
Compiled for x86 CPU with extensions: MMX MMX2 SSE SSE2 SSSE3 CMOV
get_path('codecs.conf') -> '/Applications/MPlayer OSX Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended-mt.mpBinaries/Contents/Resources/codecs.conf'
Reading /Applications/MPlayer OSX Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended-mt.mpBinaries/Contents/Resources/codecs.conf: Can't open '/Applications/MPlayer OSX Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended-mt.mpBinaries/Contents/Resources/codecs.conf': No such file or directory
Reading /Users/adrian/dev/mplayer/mplayer/usrs/local/etc/mplayer/codecs.conf: Can't open '/Users/adrian/dev/mplayer/mplayer/usrs/local/etc/mplayer/codecs.conf': No such file or directory
Using built-in default codecs.conf.
Usage:   mplayer [options] [url|path/]filename

Basic options: (complete list in the man page)
 -vo <drv>        select video output driver ('-vo help' for a list)
 -ao <drv>        select audio output driver ('-ao help' for a list)
 vcd://<trackno>  play (S)VCD (Super Video CD) track (raw device, no mount)
 dvd://<titleno>  play DVD title from device instead of plain file
 -alang/-slang    select DVD audio/subtitle language (by 2-char country code)
 -ss <position>   seek to given (seconds or hh:mm:ss) position
 -nosound         do not play sound
 -fs              fullscreen playback (or -vm, -zoom, details in the man page)
 -x <x> -y <y>    set display resolution (for use with -vm or -zoom)
 -sub <file>      specify subtitle file to use (also see -subfps, -subdelay)
 -playlist <file> specify playlist file
 -vid x -aid y    select video (x) and audio (y) stream to play
 -fps x -srate y  change video (x fps) and audio (y Hz) rate
 -pp <quality>    enable postprocessing filter (details in the man page)
 -framedrop       enable frame dropping (for slow machines)

Basic keys: (complete list in the man page, also check input.conf)
 <-  or  ->       seek backward/forward 10 seconds
 down or up       seek backward/forward  1 minute
 pgdown or pgup   seek backward/forward 10 minutes
 < or >           step backward/forward in playlist
 p or SPACE       pause movie (press any key to continue)
 q or ESC         stop playing and quit program
 + or -           adjust audio delay by +/- 0.1 second
 o                cycle OSD mode:  none / seekbar / seekbar + timer
 * or /           increase or decrease PCM volume
 x or z           adjust subtitle delay by +/- 0.1 second
 r or t           adjust subtitle position up/down, also see -vf expand

 * * * SEE THE MAN PAGE FOR DETAILS, FURTHER (ADVANCED) OPTIONS AND KEYS * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using [MPlayerX](http://code.google.com/p/mplayerx/) from Google Code without problems on OSX 10.6.3

**EDIT:** I read your edit.... MPlayerX works fine, but I don't use it from the command line. Don't know if it can be done, but I doubt it.